# Do you get back one rent if you pay double rent after you leave your apartment?

Tags: germany, taxes, rental

In Germany, there is (usually) a 3 month notice for when you leave your rented apartment. Sometimes, during these months, the renter pays double rent: at the place the new apartment they're renting, and the old one.

I was told that one can get one of the rents amount back, specifically the cheaper one. Is this documented somewhere, and if yes, how can a person go about taking the money back? Is the information supposed to be filled with the tax return?

Comment: Are you asking about getting money back from the government, or getting tax credit for the double payments, or getting money back from the owner of the property you've moved from?

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica money back from the government in form of taxes paid or the rent itself. Regarding money back from the owner, I don't think that's possible.

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question. In California (and I presume in other US states as well), a landlord cannot usually receive rent for the same period from both the tenant who departed as well as the (different) tenant who just moved in. The departing tenant's claim, however, is against the landlord, and not against the government or its taxing authority.